# When EditText goes fullscreen, its not respecting my theme colors

Tags: android, android-styles

I have an `EditText` and I want it to go fullscreen mode when it landscape mode. This happens perfectly well. However it is not respecting my `primaryColor` or `accentColor` etc. Below is a screenshot of how it is now.

What I want to do is (I show an edited screenshot with photoshop of these changes I want to make):

1. Change color of highlight to 50% opacity red
2. Change underline color to red
3. Change cursor color to red
4. Change text selection handles color to red

May you please advise?

This is my styles.xml right now:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDark</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

## I used Photoshop to show what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: can you post some screenshots of the problem?

Comment: @OnurA. thanks, I added screenshot of how it is, and a Photoshoped version of what I am trying to achieve.